# Composition of n-ary functions on natural numbers in Coq

Tags: coq, function-composition

I want to define a function `compose` which composes `f : nat ^^ n --> nat` with `g1 ... gn : nat ^^ m --> nat` such that

```
compose n m f g1 ... gn x1 ... xm
```

is equal to

```
f (g1 x1 ... xm) ... (gn x1 ... xm)
```

Using the [standard library for n-ary functions](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Numbers.NaryFunctions.html), defining it for the special case `n = 1` isn't too hard:

```
Fixpoint compose_unary (m : nat) (g : nat -> nat) :
(nat ^^ m --> nat) -> (nat ^^ m --> nat) := 
match m return ( (nat ^^ m --> nat) -> 
(nat ^^ m --> nat) ) with  
| O    => fun x => (g x)
| S m' => fun f => fun x 
       => compose_unary m' g (f x)
end.
```

As for the general case, I'm pretty sure the type declaration should be

```
Fixpoint compose (n m : nat) 
(g : nat ^^ n --> nat) : 
(nat ^^ m --> nat) ^^ n 
--> (nat ^^ m --> nat)
```

But I'm clueless how to proceed from here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I managed to do, but was not sure it is the easiest way, since I use dependent type and dependent pattern matching to encode the family `g1, ... , gn`:

```
Require Import NaryFunctions Vector.

Open Scope type.
```

First I need a function to apply a function `f: A^^n --> B` to a n-uplet `x: A^^n`:

```
Definition napply {A B:Type} (n :nat) (f: A ^^ n --> B) (x: A ^ n) : B :=
  nuncurry A B n f x.
```

Then here is your compose function:

```
Fixpoint compose {A B C: Type} (n m: nat) (f: B ^^ m --> C) (gs: Vector.t (A ^^ n --> B) m) (xs: A ^ n) {struct gs } :  C :=
  match gs in Vector.t _ m' return (B ^^ m' --> C) -> A ^ n -> C with
    | nil _ => fun f0 _ => f0
    | cons _ hd p tl => fun fs ys => compose n p (fs (napply n hd ys)) tl ys
  end f xs
.
```

This function takes a function `f : B^^m --> C` and  a collection of `m` functions of type `A^^n --> B` and builds a real function from `A ^ n` to `C`. You can currify it if necessary:

```
Fixpoint compose_n {A B C: Type} (n m: nat) (f: B ^^ m --> C) (gs: Vector.t (A ^^ n --> B) m) : A ^^ n --> C :=
      ncurry _ _ n (compose n m f gs).
```

Instantiate `A B C` with `nat` and you should have what your were looking for.

Cheers,

V.